# How to run timeshift when not logged in

Tags: 20.04, permissions, timeshift

I have an Ubuntu 20.04.4 workstation with multiple users and I'd like timeshift to run daily regardless of whether anyone is logged in.  I checked on the system today and found that timeshift has been failing and reporting the following error in the log file:

```
<<< snip >>>
[14:00:01] Main: load_app_config()
[14:00:01] IconManager: init()
[14:00:01] bin_path: /bin/tiubuntumeshift
[14:00:01] found images directory: /usr/share/timeshift/images
[14:00:01] base_path: (null)
[14:00:01] Main(): ok
[14:00:01] AppConsole: parse_arguments()
[14:00:01] Main: initialize_repo()
[14:00:01] backup_uuid=784c8ccd-c74b-4e9d-be70-e3a9faf81818
[14:00:01] backup_parent_uuid=
[14:00:01] Setting snapshot device from config file
[14:00:01] Main: initialize_repo(): exit
[14:00:01] AppConsole: start_application()
[14:00:01] 
[14:00:01] Snapshot device not available
[14:00:01] Device not found: UUID='784c8ccd-c74b-4e9d-be70-e3a9faf81818'
[14:00:01] exit_app()
[14:00:01] crontab -l
[14:00:01] Failed to read cron tab
[14:00:01] crontab -l
[14:00:01] Failed to read cron tab
[14:00:01] Cron task exists: /etc/cron.d/timeshift-hourly
[14:00:01] unmount_target_device()
[14:00:01] clean_logs()
[14:00:01] rm -rf '/tmp/Sst3u[14:00:01] Main: load_app_config()
[14:00:01] IconManager: init()
[14:00:01] bin_path: /bin/timeshift
[14:00:01] found images directory: /usr/share/timeshift/images
[14:00:01] base_path: (null)
[14:00:01] Main(): ok
[14:00:01] AppConsole: parse_arguments()
[14:00:01] Main: initialize_repo()
[14:00:01] backup_uuid=784c8ccd-c74b-4e9d-be70-e3a9faf81818
[14:00:01] backup_parent_uuid=
[14:00:01] Setting snapshot device from config file
[14:00:01] Main: initialize_repo(): exit
[14:00:01] AppConsole: start_application()
[14:00:01] 
[14:00:01] Snapshot device not available
[14:00:01] Device not found: UUID='784c8ccd-c74b-4e9d-be70-e3a9faf81818'
[14:00:01] exit_app()
[14:00:01] crontab -l
[14:00:01] Failed to read cron tab
[14:00:01] crontab -l
[14:00:01] Failed to read cron tab
[14:00:01] Cron task exists: /etc/cron.d/timeshift-hourly
[14:00:01] unmount_target_device()
[14:00:01] clean_logs()
[14:00:01] rm -rf '/tmp/Sst3u9bB'9bB'
```

When I run timeshift "on demand", I have success.  The log file looks like this...

```
<<< snip >>>
[11:47:41] Main: load_app_config()
[11:47:41] App config loaded: /etc/timeshift.json
[11:47:41] IconManager: init()automatically 
[11:47:41] bin_path: /usr/bin/timeshift-gtk
[11:47:41] found images directory: /usr/share/timeshift/images
[11:47:41] Main(): ok
[11:47:41] Main: initialize_repo()
[11:47:41] backup_uuid=784c8ccd-c74b-4e9d-be70-e3a9faf81818
[11:47:41] backup_parent_uuid=
[11:47:41] Setting snapshot device from config file
[11:47:41] repo: creating from uuid
[11:47:41] SnapshotRepo: from_uuid(): RSYNC
[11:47:41] uuid=784c8ccd-c74b-4e9d-be70-e3a9faf81818
[11:47:41] SnapshotRepo: init_from_device()
<<< snip >>>
```

Note that the backup_UUID is identical.  This seems to me like a permissions error.  The permissions on the timeshift folder on the backup drive are:

`drwxr-xr-x 9 root    root       4096 Jun 27 11:50 timeshift`

I'd rather not CHMOD the backup drive to allow everyone to write to it.  Instead, I'd like to allow timeshift to operate successfully with proper permissions when I'm not logged in.

Alternatively, maybe this is not a permissions issue at all -- I've only been using linux for about a year and still mystified by some things.

BTW, when I log in and run timeshift "on demand" (and it works) I am not logging in as root.  I'm logging in with a user associated with the following groups:

`<user> adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare HGS`

In response to comments, below, the results of `sudo lsblk -f` are:

```
NAME        FSTYPE   LABEL UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
loop0       squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/core/13250
loop1       squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/core/13308
loop2       squashfs                                                  0   100% /snap/notepadqq/855
sda                                                                            
└─sda1      ext4           5deaeefe-94e6-4f95-bf29-a0794c563de9  993.7G    38% /data
sdb                                                                            
└─sdb1      ext4           784c8ccd-c74b-4e9d-be70-e3a9faf81818    3.1T    26% /run/timeshift/backup
nvme0n1                                                                        
├─nvme0n1p1 vfat           3747-AF41                             505.8M     1% /boot/efi
└─nvme0n1p2 ext4           0806f74e-4c9b-4733-93b0-4a6f2404c261  163.4G    86% /
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: do you run `timeshift` with `sudo` or enter your password in order to run? If so, you are running as `root` even though you're logged in as your own user.

Comment: I ran timeshift from the "timeshift" gui application, logged in using an account with sudo privs.  I've used the setting in that app to have timeshift run daily.

Comment: did you need a password to start the GUI application? I assume you did, which means it's running as `root`

Comment: Yes, it asks for authentication.  So yes, you are correct.  It is running with elevated privileges.  I guess the question is, how do I give timeshift the ability to run automatically when I'm not logged in?  Do I have to set up timeshift as a cron job?

Comment: apparently Timeshift automatically sets a crontab that runs as `root` in order to do automatic updates. The issue seems to be that it can't find the device with `UUID=784c8ccd-c74b-4e9d-be70-e3a9faf81818`. Can you post output of `sudo lsblk -f`?

Comment: How is this backup device connected? The log suggests it is not available when run by cron but appears to be available at other times so it could be a case of energy management placing it in a low power state which is not waking up for the cron initiated snapshot. I’d troubleshoot by changing the permissions on the TimeShift folder to see if that causes it to work. If it does then it’s a permissions issue if not it’s something else.

Comment: @Esther, I've posted the results of `sudo lsblk -f` in my question.  @PonJar, I think this tells you how the backup device is connected.  It is a local physical backup drive mounted within the same computer (this is for backup speed and convenience; I periodically backup the backup drive to an off-site device).  Your suggestion to change the permissions temporarily is excellent; don't know why it didn't occur to me.  I will set unlimited read/write permissions to the backup drive and timeshift folder temporarily and report back.